# Get the javascript push object array in a MVC3 controller action

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

This is my javascript code:

```
var bankOptions = {};
    var playerOptions = [];
    bankOptions["BankTotalAmount"] = $("#totalBankAmountID").val();
    bankOptions["SinglePlayerAmount"] = $("#singlePlayerAmountID").val();
    while (_playerNumber != 0) {

        if (_playerNumber == 1) {
            var player1Option = {};
            player1Option["Name"] = $("#p" + _playerNumber + "Name").val();
            player1Option["Color"] = $("#p" + _playerNumber + "Color").val();

            playerOptions.push(player1Option);
        }

        if (_playerNumber == 2) {
            var player2Option = {};
            player2Option["Name"] = $("#p" + _playerNumber + "Name").val();
            player2Option["Color"] = $("#p" + _playerNumber + "Color").val();

            playerOptions.push(player2Option);
        }

        if (_playerNumber == 3) {
            var player3Option = {};
            player3Option["Name"] = $("#p" + _playerNumber + "Name").val();
            player3Option["Color"] = $("#p" + _playerNumber + "Color").val();

            playerOptions.push(player3Option);
        }

        if (_playerNumber == 4) {
            var player4Option = {};
            player4Option["Name"] = $("#p" + _playerNumber + "Name").val();
            player4Option["Color"] = $("#p" + _playerNumber + "Color").val();

            playerOptions.push(player4Option);
        }

        _playerNumber--;
    }
    alert(playerOptions);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/StartOption/setOptions/",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ bankOptions: bankOptions, playerOptions: playerOptions }),
        type: "POST",
        timeout: 10000,
        success: function (result) {

        }
    });
```

and i have this Controller class

```
public class StartOptionController : Controller
    {
        private MonopolyDB db = new MonopolyDB();

        //
        // GET: /StartOption/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult setOptions(BankOptions bankOptions, Playeroptions[] playerOptions)
        {
            //int length = (int)playerOptions.GetType().InvokeMember("length", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, playerOptions, null);
            BankAccount bankaccount = new BankAccount();
            bankaccount.ID = 1;
            bankaccount.TotalAmmount = bankOptions.BankTotalAmount;
            db.BankAccount_Table.Add(bankaccount);
            db.SaveChanges();

            //Here i want to get each (player1Option, player2Option...) object array from that playerOptions object array


            //return RedirectToAction("Index");

            return View();
        }

    }
    public class BankOptions
    {
        public int BankTotalAmount { get; set; }
        public int SinglePlayerAmount { get; set; }
    }
    public class Playeroptions
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
    }
```

My question is how i can get those object array that i push into playerOptions object array in my setOptions action?

as like i want to save each player info in my DB from playerOptions object array where i push each player info in my javascript code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well first to make it easy I would like to recommend that changes the sign of your action

from

```
public ActionResult setOptions(BankOptions bankOptions, Playeroptions[] playerOptions)
```

To

```
public ActionResult setOptions(BankOptions bankOptions, List<PlayerOptions> playerOptions)
```

That's it's going to make it easy the handle of each element of the array, and there's not problem for the framework to serialize this object.

Now to answer your question you could iterate the array like this

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult setOptions(BankOptions bankOptions, Playeroptions[] playerOptions)
    {
        //int length = (int)playerOptions.GetType().InvokeMember("length", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, playerOptions, null);
        BankAccount bankaccount = new BankAccount();
        bankaccount.ID = 1;
        bankaccount.TotalAmmount = bankOptions.BankTotalAmount;
        db.BankAccount_Table.Add(bankaccount);
        db.SaveChanges();

        //Here i want to get each (player1Option, player2Option...) object array from that playerOptions object array
        for ( int i = 0 ; i< playerOptions.Length, i++)
        {
            playerOptions[i]; //<-- this give's the specific element
        }

        //return RedirectToAction("Index");

        return View();
    }
```

Nevertheless if you follow my recommendation and changes the sign of your action you could iterate your code like this

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult setOptions(BankOptions bankOptions, List<PlayerOptions> playerOptions)
    {
        //int length = (int)playerOptions.GetType().InvokeMember("length", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, playerOptions, null);
        BankAccount bankaccount = new BankAccount();
        bankaccount.ID = 1;
        bankaccount.TotalAmmount = bankOptions.BankTotalAmount;
        db.BankAccount_Table.Add(bankaccount);
        db.SaveChanges();

        //Here i want to get each (player1Option, player2Option...) object array from that playerOptions object array
        foreach( var item in playerOptions){
             item //<--- in this variable you have the element PlayerOption
        }

        //return RedirectToAction("Index");

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: I dealt with this just yesterday and I agree that using the List<t> option is probably going to be by far the easiest to work with.

Comment: Yeap, I deal with this problem too a couple a months ago... The great of the framework it's the handle of the serialization without do anything